# Can "succeed" be used as an imperative?

Tags: verbs

In a golf video game I'm working on: "Succeed a putt from 50 feet."

This use of "succeed" bothers me whenever I see it, but I can't formalize why I think it's wrong.

Comment: The imperative is not the issue. The issue is transitivity. The transitive form of *succeed* means to follow after in a job, role, or position. If you want someone to have success, saying, "Succeed!" is certainly imperative and unremarkable. But if that verb takes a direct object, all bets are off.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you had in mind but it's common to hear "Master" or "Mastering" used in that way, as corrected by @Robusto...such as "Mastering the 50-Foot Putt" and "Mastering the Art of Baking", for example.

Comment: *Master* is too strong. *Complete, accomplish*, or *perform* is more like it. It does not take a master to luck out once.

Comment: You **MAKE** putts. Or hope you do.

Comment: 'His only son, Edward VI, succeeded Henry VIII, to the throne of England.' That is the only way I can think of using 'succeed' transitively.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the verb *[succeed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/succeed)*, as you use it, is intransitive (no object) and means

> Achieve the desired aim or result:
>   *a mission which could not possibly succeed*

The transitive verb *[succeed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/succeed)* (with an object) means

> Take over a throne, inheritance, office, or other position from

Perhaps you might consider

> - sink
> - drain
> - accomplish
> - execute

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ***succeed***, rather than *Succeed a putt from 50 feet*, add a preposition phrase:

Succeed *in making a putt* from 50 feet. OR

Succeed *in putting* 50 feet.